# Crystal Reports for Visual Studio - How to update total page count label in CrystalReportViewer as reports are loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2015 and the "Total Page Count" label in the viewer displays the active page index followed by a plus sign (until I've navigated to the last page and the plus sign disappears). The field I'm referring to is highlighted below.

[image]

I know that by including a field that calculates the total number of pages in the report (such as Page N of M), the highlighted number will display the total number of pages, but I can't use that option because it forces the entire report to be loaded before displaying it in the viewer, and the report is very large and it will take too long to load if it's forced to load the entire report, so that is not an option.

So I was hoping for a way to either have that number continuously update as new pages are loaded or to just have that number update to the total page count once all pages are finished loaded.

I'd take either option at this point, but in searching through the CrystalReportViewer class I haven't been able to find an option that could accomplish that. I haven't been able to find an event that triggers when a new page is loaded (or all pages are loaded) and I haven't been able to find a method that updates the "Total Page Count" label that I highlighted above.

Is using the "1+" method the only option I have?

Thank you, I appreciate any help.